# Ripple exchanges websocket equivalent for ripple data apiv2

Tags: api, ripple

I'm trying to get the exchanges in ripple and I found [this data API](https://data.ripple.com/v2/exchanges/%7Bbase%7D/%7Bcounter%7D) and its working. But I want to use the ripple websocket tool for some reasons. Is there any websocket equivalent for this data API?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is equivalent if you use "tx_history" command in the socket but Sorry to tell you that the json result are not equal to your specific data result.

ripple data apiv2 is being played by ajax. see the result json formatter in ripple  for exchange:

> ```
>   } else if (resp.rows.length) {
>     resp.rows[0] = {
>       base_currency: resp.rows[0].base_currency,
>       base_issuer: resp.rows[0].base_issuer,
>       base_amount: resp.rows[0].base_amount,
>       counter_amount: resp.rows[0].counter_amount,
>       counter_currency: resp.rows[0].counter_currency,
>       counter_issuer: resp.rows[0].counter_issuer,
>       rate: resp.rows[0].rate,
>       executed_time: resp.rows[0].executed_time,
>       ledger_index: resp.rows[0].ledger_index,
>       buyer: resp.rows[0].buyer,
>       seller: resp.rows[0].seller,
>       taker: resp.rows[0].taker,
>       provider: resp.rows[0].provider,
>       autobridged_currency: resp.rows[0].autobridged_currency,
>       autobridged_issuer: resp.rows[0].autobridged_issuer,
>       offer_sequence: resp.rows[0].offer_sequence,
>       tx_type: resp.rows[0].tx_type,
>       tx_index: resp.rows[0].tx_index,
>       node_index: resp.rows[0].node_index,
>       tx_hash: resp.rows[0].tx_hash
>     };
>   }
>
>   res.csv(resp.rows, filename);
> } else {
>   res.json({
>     result: 'success',
>     count: resp.rows.length,
>     marker: resp.marker,
>     exchanges: resp.rows
>   });
> }   }
> ```

and it can be only access by get url :

> route: '/v2/exchanges/{:base}/{:counter}'

that is bind in there server.js:

> app.get('/v2/exchanges/:base/:counter', routes.getExchanges);

and last hint this is their database query using hbase:

> HbaseClient.getExchanges = function (options, callback) {
>   var base = options.base.currency + '|' + (options.base.issuer || ''); 
>   var counter = options.counter.currency + '|' + (options.counter.issuer
>   ||'');     var table;
>       var keyBase;
>       var startRow;
>       var endRow;
>
> var descending;
>
> var columns;
>
> if (counter.toLowerCase() > base.toLowerCase()) {
>       keyBase = base + '|' + counter;
>
> } else {
>       keyBase = counter + '|' + base;
>       options.invert = true;   }
>
> if (!options.interval) {
>       table      = 'exchanges';
>       descending = options.descending ? true : false;
>       options.unreduced = true;
>
> ```
> //only need certain columns
> if (options.reduce) {
>   columns = [
>     'd:base_amount',
>     'd:counter_amount',
>     'd:rate',
>     'f:executed_time',
>     'f:buyer',
>     'f:seller',
>     'f:taker'
>   ];
> }
> ```
>
> } else if (exchangeIntervals.indexOf(options.interval) !== -1) {
>       keyBase    = options.interval + '|' + keyBase;
>       descending = options.descending ? true : false;
>       table      = 'agg_exchanges';
>
> } else {
>       callback('invalid interval: ' + options.interval);
>       return;   }
>
> startRow = keyBase + '|' + options.start.hbaseFormatStartRow();
>   endRow   = keyBase + '|' + options.end.hbaseFormatStopRow();
>
> if (options.autobridged) {
>       options.filterstring = "DependentColumnFilter('f', 'autobridged_currency')";
>       if (columns) {
>         columns.push('f:autobridged_currency');
>       }   }
>
> this.getScanWithMarker(this, {
>       table: table,
>       startRow: startRow,
>       stopRow: endRow,
>       marker: options.marker,
>       limit: options.limit,
>       descending: descending,
>       columns: columns,
>       filterString: options.filterstring   }, function (err, resp) {
>
> ```
> if (!resp) {
>   resp = {rows: []};
> }
>
> if (!resp.rows) {
>   resp.rows = [];
> }
>
> if (options.reduce && options.unreduced) {
>   if (descending) {
>     resp.rows.reverse();
>   }
>
>   resp.reduced = reduce(resp.rows);
> } else if (table === 'exchanges') {
>   resp.rows = formatExchanges(resp.rows);
> } else {
>   resp.rows = formatAggregates(resp.rows);
> }
>
> callback(err, resp);   });
> ```

/**    * formatExchanges    */

> function formatExchanges (rows) {
>       rows.forEach(function(row) {
>         var key = row.rowkey.split('|');
>
> ```
>   delete row.base_issuer;
>   delete row.base_currency;
>   delete row.counter_issuer;
>   delete row.counter_currency;
>
>   row.base_amount    = parseFloat(row.base_amount);
>   row.counter_amount = parseFloat(row.counter_amount);
>   row.rate           = parseFloat(row.rate);
>   row.offer_sequence = Number(row.offer_sequence || 0);
>   row.ledger_index   = Number(row.ledger_index);
>   row.tx_index       = Number(key[6]);
>   row.node_index     = Number(key[7]);
>   row.time           = utils.unformatTime(key[4]).unix();
> });
>
> if (options.invert) {
>   rows = invertPair(rows);
> }
>
> return rows;   }
> ```

/**    * formatAggregates    */

> function formatAggregates (rows) {
>       rows.forEach(function(row) {
>         var key = row.rowkey.split('|');
>         row.base_volume    = parseFloat(row.base_volume),
>         row.counter_volume = parseFloat(row.counter_volume),
>         row.buy_volume     = parseFloat(row.buy_volume),
>         row.count          = Number(row.count);
>         row.open           = parseFloat(row.open);
>         row.high           = parseFloat(row.high);
>         row.low            = parseFloat(row.low);
>         row.close          = parseFloat(row.close);
>         row.vwap           = parseFloat(row.vwap);
>         row.close_time     = Number(row.close_time);
>         row.open_time      = Number(row.open_time);
>       });
>
> ```
> if (options.invert) {
>   rows = invertPair(rows);
> }
>
> return rows;   }
> ```

/**   * if the base/counter key was inverted, we need to swap   * some of the values in the results   */

> function invertPair (rows) {
>       var swap;
>       var i;
>
> ```
> if (options.unreduced) {
>
>   for (i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
>     rows[i].rate = 1/rows[i].rate;
>
>     //swap base and counter vol
>     swap = rows[i].base_amount;
>     rows[i].base_amount    = rows[i].counter_amount;
>     rows[i].counter_amount = swap;
>
>     //swap buyer and seller
>     swap = rows[i].buyer;
>     rows[i].buyer  = rows[i].seller;
>     rows[i].seller = swap;
>   }
>
> } else {
>
>   for (i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
>
>     //swap base and counter vol
>     swap = rows[i].base_volume;
>     rows[i].base_volume    = rows[i].counter_volume;
>     rows[i].counter_volume = swap;
>
>     //swap high and low
>     swap = 1/rows[i].high;
>     rows[i].high = 1/rows[i].low;
>     rows[i].low  = swap;
>
>     //invert open, close, vwap
>     rows[i].open  = 1/rows[i].open;
>     rows[i].close = 1/rows[i].close;
>     rows[i].vwap  = 1/rows[i].vwap;
>
>     //invert buy_volume
>     rows[i].buy_volume /= rows[i].vwap;
>   }
> }
>
> return rows;   }
> ```

/**    * reduce    * reduce all rows    */

> function reduce (rows) {
>
> ```
> var buyVolume = 0;
> var reduced = {
>   open: 0,
>   high: 0,
>   low: Infinity,
>   close: 0,
>   base_volume: 0,
>   counter_volume: 0,
>   buy_volume: 0,
>   count: 0,
>   open_time: 0,
>   close_time: 0
> };
>
> rows = formatExchanges(rows);
> ```

```
// filter out small XRP amounts
```

> rows = rows.filter(function(row) {
>         if (options.base.currency === 'XRP' && row.base_amount < 0.0005) {
>           return false;
>         } else if (options.counter.currency === 'XRP' && row.counter_amount < 0.0005) {
>           return false;
>         } else {
>           return true;
>         }
>       });
>
> ```
> if (rows.length) {
>   reduced.open_time  = moment.unix(rows[0].time).utc().format();
>   reduced.close_time = moment.unix(rows[rows.length-1].time).utc().format();
>
>   reduced.open  = rows[0].rate;
>   reduced.close = rows[rows.length -1].rate;
>   reduced.count = rows.length;
>
> } else {
>   reduced.low = 0;
>   return reduced;
> }
>
> rows.forEach(function(row) {
>   reduced.base_volume    += row.base_amount;
>   reduced.counter_volume += row.counter_amount;
>
>   if (row.rate < reduced.low)  reduced.low  = row.rate;
>   if (row.rate > reduced.high) reduced.high = row.rate;
>
>   if (row.buyer === row.taker) {
>     reduced.buy_volume += row.base_amount;
>   }
> });
>
>
> reduced.vwap = reduced.counter_volume / reduced.base_volume;
> return reduced;   } };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make a custom websocket that make your `RPC` call upgrade to 1.1 http protocol (ws).

In `nodejs` you can simply

```
// for http
var http = require('http');

// for websocket
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket")

var options = {
  host: 'URL-RPC-HERE',
  port: '80',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'Content-Length': post_data.length
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  // after getting the response wich is the <res>
  // we can upgrade it to ws
  upToWebsocket(res);
});

//Upgrade to websocket
var upToWebsocket = function(json) {
  var server = ws.createServer(function (conn) {
    conn.on("json", function (str) {
      conn.sendText(str.toUpperCase()+"!!!")
  })

    conn.on("close", function (code, reason) {
      console.log("Connection closed")
    })
  }).listen(8001)
}
```

And also if you have Rippled running on a server this does not help because there's no RPC or WS that supports exchange API.